# Scraping linked-in profile to get user email using NodeJS Puppeteer and scrapedin

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, linkedin-api

Dears, I'm now working on a project that requires me to scrape the public linked-in profiles to get some info like email, name, company, title, photo (some basic information)
I write it with NodeJS, using Puppeteer and library called [scrapedin](https://github.com/linkedtales/scrapedin)

This library requires me to log in to LinkedIn with e-mail and password, I created a dummy linked-in account to use it for this library, it worked fine in localhost, but once I uploaded it to the server I should use cookies to login

and here is the problem, after maybe 30 min linked-in restricted the account and I can't use it anymore!

How could I solve this problem
Is there another library for linked-in **scraping** I can use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn likely restricted your account because they don't want bot activity on their website. You could try to make your script act more human, for example by inserting random wait times between actions using `setTimeout()`. It could also help to spend some time creating a new human-like dummy account that is less easy to detect as a bot, for example by uploading a profile picture and writing some text.
You could also make the script do some human actions like pressing random like buttons between the scrape actions.